# Interesting Binary Day

Tags: discussion

Today is an interesting day. Same rep on two most visited sites!

[image]

And the 2 ^^ 15 is also interesting.

Comment: Some nasty guy upvoted you just to break this coincidence!

Comment: @clabacchio - LOL.....now 2.

Comment: I have a funny feeling that this a subtle way to ask for rep... LOL ;)

Comment: This was staged? or an accident?

Comment: Cool, Michael! It boggles the mind.  My mind, at least :)

Comment: @laptop2d - I noticed that the two totals were close so I stepped up participation in DIY to get the totals close to same. At one point on that particular day they showed the above totals. It did not last for long!!